# Flutter showSearch keyboard search

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am very new to Flutter and Dart so I am trying to build a simple search app with queries based on a word typed in Flutters showSearch search bar. I understand the listtile that is built to show suggestions to the user, and tapping that suggestion will activate the buildresults widget. However, I want to enable the search button on the keyboard to simply search the inputted word, rather than tapping on the limited suggestion list.
[Simple android keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By4ov.png)

When the button is clicked normally, the keyboard is closed the buildresults is not activated. So far you have to actually click a suggested listtile option. Is there a way to enable the keyboard's search button to search the inputted text? or Is the user limited to the suggested listtile options? I will list my showSearch delegate below:

```
class StockDelegate extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final stocks = [
    "IBM",
    "NKLAW",
    "DKNGZ",
    "DRD",
    "PRTS",
    "TSLA",
    "KIRK",
    "VBIV"
  ];
  final suggested = ["IBM", "TSLA", "BNTX"];

  @override
  // TODO: implement textInputAction

  // TODO: implement textInputAction
  TextInputAction get textInputAction => super.textInputAction;

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    //actions for app bar
    StockProvider _stockProvider =
        Provider.of<StockProvider>(context, listen: true);
    return [
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: () {
            query = '';
          }),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    //Leading icon on the left of the app bar
    return IconButton(
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
          progress: transitionAnimation,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          close(context, null);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    //build results code 
   
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // show when someone search for something
    stocks.insert(0, query.toString());

    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? suggested
        : stocks.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () async {
          Provider.of<StockProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .searchBySymbol(suggestionList[index]);

          if (!stocks.contains(suggestionList[index]))
            suggestionList.add(suggestionList[index]);

          showResults(context);
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
        title: Text(suggestionList[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether you know about [onSubmitted property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) or not, which is used in the `TextField/Text/TextFormField`. Since, I cannot see your `TexFormField/Text/TextField` anywhere, but I think you must be using it somewhere.

So, this is how `onFieldSubmitted` used, which does the job which you want, that is, **when the user hit on the magnifying lens on the keypad, it runs your function**

```
              TextFormField(
                controller: _yourTextEditingController,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                onFieldSubmitted: (){
                     // here you do your operation when you hit the 
                     // keypad magnifying lens
                     // check with print()
                     print('Pressed via keypad');
                }
              )
```

Don't get confused with `onSubmitted` name, `onFieldSubmitted` is used in `TextFormField/Text/TextField`, which uses `onSubmitted` property. I hope that answers your question :) Let me know, is that was the thing you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Unfortunately I am using the showSearch widget which builds the StockDelegate class I have listed above. The showSearch widget is in this folllowing comment below. I am not sure where I can accesss a TextFormField using the showSearch widget

Comment: `Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    StockProvider _stockProvider =
        Provider.of<StockProvider>(context, listen: false);



    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text('Stock Search Page'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              tooltip: 'Search',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: StockDelegate());
              },
            )
          ],
        ),`

Comment: You'll see this is this is only within the AppBar and 'showSearch delegate: StockDelegate() is represents in the code above.

Comment: @Legz4Dayz did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Override `showResults()` method similar to `buildSuggestions()`.

override `showResults` method as follow:

```
  @override
  void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    super.showResults(context);
    showSuggestions(context);
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).